# Strange line/artifact in graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Graph containing issue]

This graph that I plotted in Matplotlib for Python makes a strange line across part of the graph. The x axis is in Unix time, formatted to a readable format. The y axis is a different array of floats. What should I check for to correct this error?

Here is the code used to draw the graph:

```
data = pd.read_csv('candles.csv')
data['date'] = [dt.date(1970,1,1) + dt.timedelta(seconds=time) for time in data['date']]

plt.plot(data['date'],data['close'])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this the BTC value? :D

Comment: Not a matplotlib expert, but would an element in your csv file that is out of order cause that effect?

Comment: @MMF close, it's the ascent profile of a rocket heading towards the moon.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That would be it, thanks!

Comment: @ME914 so it takes 3 years for the rocket to get to the moon? haha, It's definitely btc ! :D

Answer (score 1):

These kind of lines are almost always produced by an out of order element in your lists/arrays.  Try sorting by the `x` values, e.g.

```
xx = data['date']
idx = np.argsort(xx)
xx = xx[idx]
yy = data['close'][idx]
plt.plot(xx, yy)
```